# Actions and parameters are not capturing values properly in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created one parameter Named "Purpose" under actions and parameter. I gave it as required parameter and in the prompt I gave as "What is the purpose ?". Entity type I am trying is @sys.any.

After prompt what ever I gave like "Child protective services" or "Child protective service" I am getting reply from simulator that "I missed that can you say that again" or "Sorry I couldn't understand".

This was working two weeks before and suddenly its happening like this in DF. I tried other way also by creating user defined entity and nothing helps.

Any update happened in dialog flow and do I have to change anything to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bug! Since yesterday Google Assistant is no longer recognizing both Intents and parameters properly. Lots of people are facing that problem.

I already opened a issue and am waiting for a solution.

_DM

Comment: Thank you. Then let me wait for google to resolve this issue.